# issue with int to float

Tags: c++, constructor-chaining

Here is my issue. I have a constructor that makes a color from 4 floats ranging 0 to 1. I want to add compatibility with 0 to 255 int so I have another constructor like this:

```
AguiColor::AguiColor( int r, int g, int b, int a )
{
 double num = 1.0f / 255.0f;
    AguiColor((float)(r * num), (float)(g * num), (float)(b * num), (float)(a * num));

}
```

However this does not work. The rgba float components become strange numbers. What is wrong with this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "strange numbers"? I.e. What numbers are you expecting, and what numbers are you getting?

Comment: Why don't you simply provide two constructors?

Comment: @Ed: Based on "I have another constructor" and the fact that he's getting garbage data, not a stack overflow, I'm pretty sure he does have two constructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++03 doesn't support constructor delegation (a/k/a chaining).  When you call that other constructor, Java-style, it creates a temporary object, without affecting the object under construction.

This might fix it, but isn't as efficient as initializing the members directly would be.

```
AguiColor::AguiColor( int r, int g, int b, int a )
{
  double num = 1.0f / 255.0f;
  *this = AguiColor((float)(r * num), (float)(g * num), (float)(b * num), (float)(a * num));
}
```

Comment: would this create a memory leak, should I delete this, first?